# Tinkoff notify получает пустой REQUST

Tags: php, request, уведомления

подключаю интернет-эквайеринг от тинкофф бизнес. Все настроит и работает. Но не приходят уведомления о статусе платежа. Точнее они вроде как приходят, но пустые. У меня тестовый магазин и при оплате должен приходить post запрос на страницу которую я указал. Там я пока сделал просто запись в базу данных $_REQUEST и всегда выходит пустой массив, пробывал сам отправить пост запрос на эту страницу все записывает.

```
<?php
include_once('../../connect_db.php');


$response = $_REQUEST;
$response = json_encode($response);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `payments` (id_user, count, price, status) VALUES ('1', '2', '3', '$response')";
$connect_db->query($sql);
```

Подскажите что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте file_get_contents, сам мучался искал, но потом нашёл методом проб и ошибок такую вещь

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```